# How to make a rope bridge in blender?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

So, I want to model a rope bridge in the image below. I attempted to do this by making the individual bridge steps and then applying a curve modifier and then an array modifier.

[image]

However, it'a yielding incorrect results:

[image]

How do I rectify this? If there is no viable solution for my method any other attempt/method are also acceptable provided they are not too high poly and are easy to unwrap. 
This is my setup:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you rotate the object 90 degrees in the z axis?

Comment: @tacofisher all individual elements rotate, but they don't align

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the modifier of the array should be on top then below the curve modifier.

And the Rotation and scale should be applied

Below i have change the order of the array on top and then the curve modifier.

Then applied the scale and rotation. (Ctrl+A)

Rotate at Z axis 90 degree

With the array increased the count and adjusted the bridge.

Press ctrl+N to flip normals

Adjust the curve to align the starting point

[image]

Answer (score 1):

its caused by the local rotations and the modifier stack.
Make sure that  for objects all local y is like world y direction.
Your modifier order should then be:

do a CTRL + A aplly rotation for all opjbects
Edit walkpath direction becomes Y, again ctrl +A aply rotation

mirror on x axis

array (0.00  (x
      (1.00  (y
      (0.000 (z

curve (curve on -y

Maybe when done rotate step object over its local y press RYY 180 / 90

then you get this : [image]